# vlookup matching with one column but not several

Tags: excel

Got the following issue.

My sheet below.

When I'm doing a vlookup , column to column like below, I have the value **LM-UN-F-GT25** that is retrieved

`=vlookup(A3;C2:C58;1;false)`

When I'm doing a vlookup , column to  a list of columns like below, nothing is retrieved...

`=vlookup(A3;B2:E58;1;false)`

[image: Spreadsheet]

Why?

Thanks.

**EDIT** It seems that only the value on the B column are seen when doing the lookup on a list of columns...Weird, no?

Comment: What are you expecting it to retrieve? In the the first case your lookup table only has 1 column (column c). In the second case you lookup table starts with column B and LM-UN-F-LE25 isn't in column B.

Comment: Hi MattyG, `=RECHERCHEV(A3;B2:E58;1;FAUX)` I'm looking for the value in the cell A3 within the list starting at B2 and encompassing every cells until E58. Does it make sense to you?

Cheers.

Comment: Andy, the question is more of what are you trying to return with the vlookup.  In the first example, you're return back the same result that you searched for.  Normally vlookup is used to find values in another column based on the first column matching.  Are you trying to return the original code? Or something else?

Comment: Hi Amoy,

I'm trying to know if the value I have in cell A3 is present in the other cells namely B2 to E58. Is my answer clearer ?

Comment: Dear Pnuts, I'm doing that already. 

But how come that vlookup is not working with several columns ... ? This is the essence of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLookUp only searches for the search value in the first column of the range. Your search value is not in the first column of the range B2:E58, which is column B. Your search value is in column C. That is why you get no results for your second formula.

From Microsoft: "[VLookup] searches for a value in the ***first column*** of a table array and returns a value in the same row from another column in the table array."

See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Since you say you just want to know "if the value I have in cell A3 is present in the other cells namely B2 to E58", perhaps CountIf would be a better fit. Try:

```
=CountIF(B2:E58,A3)
```

That will tell you how many times the value in cell A3 appears in the range B2:E58.

Or maybe:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:E58,A3)>0,"Value Present","Not Present")
```

That will show the phrase "Value Present" if the value is present and "Not Present" if it isn't.